# aframe-state component to attach/detach components

Tags: three.js, aframe

I am trying to attach/detach components to entity based on certain conditions.

For example, I want to be able to track two conditions -

1. A player has clicked on play button and
2. The time count down is not yet zero

before I attach a component to an entity.

I looked at the following component from Kevin - https://github.com/ngokevin/kframe/tree/master/components/state/

where there is an example on attaching/detaching components based on boolean value. Here is an extract from his documentation

> There's a bind-toggle component which will attach and detach a
>   component entirely based on a boolean value.

```
<a-entity bind-toggle__raycastable="isRaycastable"></a-entity>
```

But, it's not clear where that boolean value is being set before the raycastable component gets attached to the entity.

I am looking for a solution where I can write the entity as follows

```
<a-entity bind-toggle__move="condition1 && condition2"></a-entity>
```

where the component "move" gets attached to the entity when condition 1 (play button is clicked) and condition 2( time count down is not zero) are satisfied. I need to know where to set the values for condition1 and condition2.

If you could please provide a working example for this then that would be great.

I can attach a codepen if that would make it easier to understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have two events: `buttonclicked`, and `countdownzero` emitted to the scene in the respective components.

Then in the state:

```
buttonclicked: function (state) {
  state.buttonClicked = true;
},

countdownzero: function (state) {
  state.countdownFinished = true;
}
```

Then can do `bind-toggle__move="buttonClicked && countdownFinished`. Let me know if you want clarification!

Comment: One question though Kevin, how do I declare a value for state.buttonClicked as false in the state and only switch it to true when buttonClicked event gets fired? Do I need to write another event handler such as buttonNotClicked which will have state.buttonClicked = false;?

Comment: `initialState: {buttonClicked: false}`. If you want to unset it then yeah, another listener.